# MySQL: Fastest way to batch update using results from (select?) table

Tags: mysql

I have a table with over 7.000.000 books, both ebooks (about 500K) and real books.
I have added a parent_ean column for ebooks and want to fill them with ean number from real books, where the author and title are the same.

Here is what I have thus far (alternative A):

```
UPDATE books as ebooks, books as parents
SET ebooks.parent_ean = parents.ean
WHERE (
  parents.title = ebooks.title AND parents.author = ebooks.author
  AND parents.format NOT LIKE "%Digital%"
  AND ebooks.format LIKE "%Digital%"
  AND ebooks.parent_ean = ""
  );
```

I am not sure this is the fastest way (the query is still running :-/) or that it's working as expected (can't see it until it's done). Is there another, better way?

Here is an alternative B (slightly modified above. c=ebooks, p=parents):

```
UPDATE books as c,
  (SELECT ean, title, author FROM books
   WHERE format NOT LIKE "%Digital%") as p
SET c.parent_ean = p.ean
WHERE (
  p.title = c.title AND
  p.author = c.author AND
  c.format LIKE "%Digital%" AND
  c.parent_ean = "");
```

The alternative B feels faster than A (but it's still running). Maybe there's an even better way?

Comment: Do you actually have values similar to Digital in the `format` column? The wildcard search using `like %digital%` will not make use of indexes on that column.

Comment: If a format is like "Digital / XXX" then it's an ebook. Otherwise a normal book.

Comment: I'd recommend removing the % sign before Digital in that case. You can keep the % after it, but removing the sign will at least enable use of indexes if they have been created on that column.

Comment: Speed may also be affected by how well indexed your table is. Consider posting your schema.

Comment: both ean and parent_ean are indexed; author, title and format are not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
UPDATE books as a INNER JOIN books as b
ON b.title = a.title AND b.author = a.author
SET a.parent_ean = b.ean
WHERE SUBSTRING(a.format,1,7) = "Digital"
AND SUBSTRING(b.format,1,7) <> "Digital"
AND a.parent_ean = ""
```

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM books as a join books as b
ON b.title = a.title AND b.author = a.author
WHE' at line 3

Comment: You can use a join, but not quite like this. It would follow the form `UPDATE books a LEFT join books b ON <condition> SET .... `

Comment: Owh my, I'm sorry... I though this is SQL Server, wait.. I'll fix it up.

Comment: @ColourDalnet Just started the query 3 minutes ago. My version was running for over 40 Minutes, so I stopped it. Will let you know if it finishes faster!

Comment: @RomanSemko : better split the task with 100.000 rows first and then compared the time.

Comment: @ColourDalnet How do I do that? Just adding "Limit 10000" at the end?

Comment: @RomanSemko `UPDATE TOP(100000) ... ` or just try 1000 if it takes so much time.

Comment: I'm sorry, mysql didn't support `TOP`, try with `LIMIT` in the end.

Comment: @ColourDalnet LIMIT is not supported by mysql if there is a JOIN in UPDATE. I guess I will have to do the whole thing.

Comment: I see, or maybe make a temporary table and copy 1000 rows for testing.